# If num1 or num2 don‘t equal 0

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in Python and I have a question:
So if I have 2 different numbers, and if either one of these numbers equals to 0 then I should return the absolute value of the number that isn‘t 0.
How can I do that?
I knnow how to use abs(a or b) and how to return values but I have difficulty writing the algorithm for the return the value that isn‘t 0.

Hope someone can help me, would be greatful :)

Comment: What have you tried (written) so far; why isn’t it working as expected?  (Please update the *question*.)

Comment: What should the function return if neither or both of the numbers are 0?

Comment: Both = return None and if neither then I can continue writing the code. I just have a problem writing this part for some reason…

Comment: And if both are != 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you are looking for classical nested tests. Having nested test ensures that each test will occur only once (in case it might be expensive).

```
def your_func(a,b):
    if a == 0: # you could use: if not a
        if b == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return abs(b)
    elif b == 0:
        return abs(a)
    else:
        # the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

`abs(a or b)` already does pretty much exactly what you want. Basically, `a or b` behaves (for numbers) like `a if a != 0 else b`. If you want to return `None` if both are `0`, you can add another `or None` after that, meaning "return None if the absolute value is zero".

```
def f(a, b):
    return abs(a or b) or None

print(f(0, -4), f(3, 0), f(4, -3), f(0, 0))
# 4 3 4 None
```

If both numbers are `!= 0`, this will just return the first value. If you want to return `None` in this case, too, you can use the slightly more cryptic `None if a and b else abs(a or b) or None` or `not (a and b) and abs(a or b) or None` if you want to stick with `and` and `or`.

Comment: Please don't assign the result of lambda expressions to a variable. It is against PEP8 style guidelines. Just use a regular function definition statement. The *entire point* of a lambda expression is to create an anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

what happens when both numbers are not 0?
or both are 0?
in this example i just returned 0:

```
def func1(a,b):
    #if both  number are zero
    if a == b == 0:
        return 0
    elif a == 0:
        return abs(b)
    elif b == 0:
        return abs(a)
    #if both of the numbers are not zero
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).